# Put Image on Parent Form Background

Tags: c#

I am using MDI parent form and I've put Background image on that. Now I am Adding two Dock Panel on the Parent Form. I've Changed Background of both the panel to Transparent. but when I run Background is not visible.

Comment: I have same problem like this

Comment: It will be hard to solve your problem not seeing your code.

Comment: You should include your code and your attempts and error messages in the question.. Otherwise how will people recreate your issue?

Comment: I've put screen shot for my application. Panels are not dynamically generated. my form is having backgroud image and panels are transparent. http://prntscr.com/4gyllj

Comment: There __really is no such thing as a transparent control__ in Winforms, if that's what you are using. You could assigen the appropriate portions of the image to the Panels as their Background images, though.

Comment: I think Panel Could be transparent in Winforms application. issue is just because I've change property MDIContainer to true. else it is working fine.

Comment: The form's background is covered by the dark-gray MDI client window so you can't see it.  Use http://bobpowell.net/mdiback.aspx

Comment: Hm, I can see a BackgroundImage on the MDI parent form alright. But any Controls on it will cover it, their  Transparent color not working, as usual.